# Writing to txt file reach out of memory ? C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to write huge lines to  a .txt file in a C# Application, around 20-30 thousand lines :

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {   
    var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

    // the code that you want to measure comes here
    List <string> firstListTrade= new List<string>();
    List <string> secondListTrade= new List<string>();
    firstListTrade= System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\File1.txt").ToList();
    secondListTrade=System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\Fil2.txt").ToList();

    string resultOne = "C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\resultOutput1.txt";
    string resultatsTwoo = "C:\\Users\\elbb001\\Desktop\\resultOutput2.txt";

    //Sorting lists
    firstListTrade=  firstListTrade.OrderBy(q => q).ToList();
    secondListTrade= secondListTrade.OrderBy(q => q).ToList();

    // Write the string array to a new file named "WriteLines.txt".
    StreamWriter outputFileOne = new StreamWriter(resultatsOne);
    StreamWriter outputFileTwoo = new StreamWriter(resultatsTwoo);
    int i = firstListTrade.Count();
    int j = secondListTrade.Count();
    int endofFile = 0;
    foreach (string trade in secondListTrade)
    {
      endofFile++;
      if (!firstListTrade.Contains(trade))
      {
        outputFileOne.WriteLine("Number : " + trade + " exist in first list but not second");
      }
      if(endofFile==i)
      {
        outputFileOne.WriteLine("End of file : " + endofFile);
      }

      outputFileOne.Flush();
    }

    endofFile = 0;
    foreach (string trade in firstListTrade)
    {
      endofFile++;
      if (!secondListTrade.Contains(trade))
      {
        outputFileTwoo.WriteLine("Number : " + trade + " exist in second but not in first ");
      }

      if (endofFile == j)
      {
        outputFileTwoo.WriteLine("End of file : "+ endofFile);
      }
    }

    watch.Stop();
    var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
    Console.WriteLine("Done in  : " + elapsedMs.ToString());
    System.Console.ReadKey();
  }
}
```

And I compiled and received no error , but when I opened the file I saw the results I want , but when I scrolled all the way down I noticed at the end of file this sentence :

> " Trade number :  22311    "

But when I used breakpoints on the end of file , it was reached in code but not written in the file?

What could have gone wrong? Did it reach out of memory? or the txt file can't write anymore?

Comment: Please post a more complete example. What is the type of `otherTradeList`? What is the sifnificance of the `i` variable? Helps us help you.

Comment: Why not just add `endofFile` to the end of the list, and just iterate like normal?

Comment: The line `**BLANK BLANK BLANK*` is coming from somewhere, and not from the framework. Something you are doing is creating it.

Comment: Depending on how you're writing to the file, you probably need to flush and close the file.  Likely using a Using statement will handle some / all of this for you.

Comment: more information is needed for the variables used; 20-30k lines is not a problem. There is a logical error in the flow somewhere.

Comment: No lib class has both a Contains() and a WriteLine()

Comment: 20K lines isn't huge. The entire file is probably small enough to sit in a core's cache memory. Your code has a bug, but you *haven't* posted all of it, so people can't help.

Comment: Yes, that is the big mystery. What is otherTradeList? Post a [mcve]

Comment: My issue was resolved , stop downvoting for no reason or take at least the time explaining why you're downvoting . You're only polluting my day with your unnecessary negativity

Comment: People are likely downvoting you because you still have an incomplete example of your code, and the selected answer doesn't really explain what the problem is. This site is just as much about helping the next person who finds your question as it is helping you. If you expand on your sample and we can solve the underlying problem it will be a more worthwhile question for the site.

Comment: I don't think that edit helped your case at all - List<string> does not have a WriteLine method.

Comment: @PaulF Oh , due the negativity of the downvote that made me so mad . I forgot to write an important detail , I have edit and I'm sorry .What exactly I did , is filling my list by the items from twoo text file (.txt ) , compare items and write the result to 2 other .txt file . I have wrote exactly my code while changing the variable names because I just can't reveal it real names

Comment: This just goes from bad to worse - it would have been much easier for you to copy the code you were using. If this were exactly your code then firstly it would not compile (List<string> does not have a WriteLine method) secondly your output file would be empty - as it stands you are iterating through each string in the second list & then checking if it is in that very same list.

Comment: @PaulF Hello , I have carefully edit full details of the code , do you mind helping me formatting the code? so I can look in a good shape , I have tried CTLR+I but didn't work

Comment: Formatted as requested - as I said earlier though would you rather fix the real problem rather than hide it - I note that in your first loop you have the Flush, but not in the second - so you may come across the same issue in the second file. See the updated answer that does not require calling Flush. You could also simplify your code by using the Linq [Except](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.7.1) method to find all entries that are in one list but not the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to new question, here is the answer:

```
StreamWriter outputFileTwoo = new StreamWriter(resultatsTwoo);
List <string> firstListThatIcantRevealItName= new List<string>();
List <string> secondListThatIcantRevealItName= new List<string>();
firstListThatIcantRevealItName=System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\blabla.txt").ToList();
secondListThatIcantRevealItName=System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\potto.txt").ToList();

using(StreamWriter outputFileOne = new StreamWriter(resultatsOne))
{
  foreach (string trade in secondListThatIcantRevealItName)
  {
    endofFile++;
    if (!secondListThatIcantRevealItName.Contains(trade))
    {
      outputFileOne.WriteLine("Trade number : " + trade + " exist in first list  but not in second list ");
    }
    if(endofFile==i)
    {
      outputFileOne.WriteLine(endofFile);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @rene It did resolve my issue , I don't see any problem upvoting him

Comment: What is the change apart from the normally unnecessary call to `Flush()`? This would only help if the code didn't close the stream, ie a bug. *Flushing* only covers up the bug, it doesn't remove it

Comment: @user3752718 no it didn't, it covered it up. Did you remember to *close* the stream before exiting your program? Or were 4K of data lost because they were still in the output buffer? That's a bug of your code. `Flush()` covers it up by forcing the buffer out on every iteration and harming performance

Comment: @user3752718 if `Flush` helped, you should *remove* it and put the definition of `otherTradeList` in a `using` block. *That* will guarantee that the data is written out even if you forget to call `Close()`

Comment: @user3752718 no it isn't. Lists don't have `Flush` or `WriteLine` methods. Post your code. You are forgetting to close your streamwriter and your stream

Comment: @user3752718 - which would you prefer - a quick fix which clears up this particular problem or do you want to understand what the real problem is so that you can avoid other related problems in the future that this fix does not solve. It seems you object to people wanting to help you get to the root cause of your problem.

Comment: Check EDIT plz.

Comment: That's why I put edit comment :)

Comment: @rene question edit done